# How do I make an intent-filter for streaming an MP3 file?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-intent

On Android, if you type a URL to an MP3 file in the browser (or click on a link to the file) you get that "Complete action using" popup with some applications listed that can play the file (Music, StreamFurious, Streaming Media Player, Winamp, XiiaLive Lite, to name a few). How can I get my application to show up in that list?

I'm pretty sure there's an intent-filter I have to add to the AndroidManifest.xml but I have no idea what action, category, or data needs to be in it. Anyone know what I have to do? Also, is there some way I can trace intents that called on the system? That might make it easier to figure out how to do other things like this in the future.

Based on what I saw at code.google.com/p/andless/source/browse/trunk/AndroidManifest.xml?spec=svn86&r=86# I tried this:

```
<activity android:name=".Main"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/mp3" android:scheme="file" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

but that didn't do it. Then I downloaded andLess from the market and realized that app doesn't show in the "Complete action using" list either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No receiver needed. This works. When you click the link it tries to "view" the contents of the link so the intent-filter needs the view action and browsable category. And the correct data settings are listed below:

```
<activity android:name=".Main"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:pathPattern=".*mp3" android:mimeType="audio/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add this filter:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER"/>
```

### By the way, don't forget the necessary permissions...that's important.^^

oh yeah...i totally forgot to  mention you need receivers. in case  you dont know that yet. broadcast receivers..like this

```
<receiver android:name="MyPhoneReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

what basically happens here is, when a file is launched/clicked maybe from a file browser, android broadcasts and sells the file to possible applications that may be interested with the kind of file. therefore, we need to establish which files our applications will/may respond to. and that's through broadcast receivers. but you probably know that already. i hope this helped..sorry for the delay i was afk.

i am editting this again...you need this inside your application tag. ^^

Comment: I tried using that, it changed nothing. Is there a specific permission that I need to add? I have Internet permission right now. The application can be opened manually and it has an EditText where you can paste the URL into and click play and that is working. The application works I just can't get it to open when you click on a link to an MP3 from the browser.

Comment: Oooo... I don't know anything about receivers. I updated the question, it has my new manifest in it. I still don't get the "complete action using" popup. It's probably something obvious that I'm doing wrong.