# Android: Will my app be destroyed by system?

Tags: android

I am making an audio player, and I was wondering will my app be destroyed in background?
I don't have background services or any services. 
When app is in background there is:
Notification with controls + changing text.
Runnable.
MediaPlayer playing.

So will system destroy app? or will it stay because of running things?
Oh and there is broadcast receiver.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.auv.als.audiovisual" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MusicPlayer"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MusicBrowser"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_music_browser"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".splash"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post `AndroidManifest.xml`. Have you seen http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html? If you are making an audio player, I would highly suggest you use `Service`s for that very reason.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I've added XML file in main post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Services should be used to keep your app active in the background:

> To accomplish this, your Activity should start a Service in which the
> upload takes place. This allows the system to properly prioritize your
> process (considering it to be more important than other non-visible
> applications) for the duration of the upload, independent of whether
> the original activity is paused, stopped, or finished.

Since you are only using activities, I believe the system will kill of your application just like any normal `Activity`.

I'd suggest your go ahead and use the Android `MediaPlayer` with a `Service`:

```
public class MyService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
    private static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.example.action.PLAY";
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ...
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PLAY)) {
            mMediaPlayer = ... // initialize it here
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // prepare async to not block main thread
        }
    }

    /** Called when MediaPlayer is ready */
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
        player.start();
    }
}
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices

### Read more

> **Process Lifecycle**
>
> The Android system attempts to keep application process around for as
> long as possible, but eventually will need to remove old processes
> when memory runs low. As described in Activity Lifecycle, the decision
> about which process to remove is intimately tied to the state of the
> user's interaction with it. In general, there are four states a
> process can be in based on the activities running in it, listed here
> in order of importance. The system will kill less important processes
> (the last ones) before it resorts to killing more important processes
> (the first ones).
>
> 1. The **foreground activity** (the activity at the top of the screen that the user is currently interacting with) is considered the most
>    important. Its process will only be killed as a last resort, if it
>    uses more memory than is available on the device. Generally at this
>    point the device has reached a memory paging state, so this is
>    required in order to keep the user interface responsive.
> 2. A **visible activity** (an activity that is visible to the user but not in the foreground, such as one sitting behind a foreground dialog)
>    is considered extremely important and will not be killed unless that
>    is required to keep the foreground activity running.
> 3. A **background activity** (an activity that is not visible to the user and has been paused) is no longer critical, so the system may
>    safely kill its process to reclaim memory for other foreground or
>    visible processes. If its process needs to be killed, when the user
>    navigates back to the activity (making it visible on the screen
>    again), its onCreate(Bundle) method will be called with the
>    savedInstanceState it had previously supplied in
>    onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) so that it can restart itself in the same
>    state as the user last left it.
> 4. An **empty process** is one hosting no activities or other application components (such as Service or BroadcastReceiver classes).
>    These are killed very quickly by the system as memory becomes low. For
>    this reason, any background operation you do outside of an activity
>    must be executed in the context of an activity BroadcastReceiver or
>    Service to ensure that the system knows it needs to keep your process
>    around.
>
> Sometimes an Activity may need to do a long-running operation that
> exists independently of the activity lifecycle itself. An example may
> be a camera application that allows you to upload a picture to a web
> site. The upload may take a long time, and the application should
> allow the user to leave the application will it is executing. To
> accomplish this, your Activity should start a Service in which the
> upload takes place. This allows the system to properly prioritize your
> process (considering it to be more important than other non-visible
> applications) for the duration of the upload, independent of whether
> the original activity is paused, stopped, or finished.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Well, see I only realized this now, this app is due tomorrow for college project. One of requirements of college is to publish it on android market. So I can't really go ahead and rebuild whole app. I was wondering maybe there is alternative solution/temporary fix. 
But thanks for that information.

Comment: @arleitiss Sorry, I just saw this. Go ahead and publish the app. Get the good grade. You can publish updates later. Put the url on here for community support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes system will kill your app when user for example clicks a mp3.  You need to handle the intents that start music playing in your app or the system will kill your app.  Because only one app can have control of the audio hardware at a time.

[How do I make an intent-filter for playing an MP3 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681998/how-do-i-make-an-intent-filter-for-playing-an-mp3-file)