# Android, commands between programs

Tags: android

I know that file managers allow you to choose, what program will open the file you chose from list of some programs.

I write music player, and i'm interested, whether is the way to put my program to such list?

I want other programs to know, that my program is a music player and can open music files; and i want my program to be able to read command from another program...

Or it is very difficult?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply add the intent filter for the type of intents you want your to allow. [This article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html) will tell you more on how to implement and explain the details: I would also read up on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6825156/1724097) that also describes intent filter for music applications more closely.